# Scraping a percent encoded URL with unicode in Scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, scrapy, url-encoding

Consider I want to scrape a site which contains the following HTML:

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premi%C3%A8r-cru-brocard-75cl">
```

This href is the percent encoding of the utf8 byte string representation of `u'https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premièr-cru-brocard-75cl'`

I get the href with Scrapy like this:

```
u = response.xpath('//a[id="mylink"]/@href').extract_first()
```

Scrapy sets the variable `u` as

```
u'http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premi%C3%A8r-cru-brocard-75cl'
```

Notice that it has incorrectly interpreted the page's byte string (that represented a unicode string) as a *unicode string itself* and as such it is the *wrong* unicode object with different unicode chars:

```
In [67]: print urllib.unquote(x)

http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premiÃ¨r-cru-brocard-75cl
```

What is actually desired is that Scrapy interprets the href as a byte string:

```
bs = 'http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premi%C3%A8r-cru-brocard-75cl'
```

so that this represents the correct unicode object, i.e.

```
In [70]: print urllib.unquote(bs).decode('utf8')

http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chablis/chablis-premièr-cru-brocard-75cl
```

The only way I've managed to get around this is with a small cleaning function that corrects the "mistake" as follows:

```
def _deal_with_encoding(url):
    # should give no encoding errors since url is ascii
    pbs = url.encode('ascii')
    # Get a regular (not percent enc) utf8 enc byte str
    bs = urllib.unquote(pbs)
    # Finally we can decode the utf8 to get correct unicode string
    return bs.decode('utf8')
```

It works but doesn't seem ideal. Is this really the only way?

Comment: Most probably, switching to Python 3 will make this less of work-around, if that's an option.

Comment: Unfortunately not an option